# Error 500 with .htaccess edits but mod_rewrite is loaded

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

as of title, I'm having problems with my .htaccess file, everything should be set fine, but has I write something as basic as

```
RewriteEngine on
```

it starts giving me that nice 500 Internal Server Error. I'm hosting on localhost on an Apache server (UNIX)

Obviously I triple checked that everything is set fine, and top of all that mod_rewrite is loaded.

Thanks for your precious help!

Comment: It's among the loaded methods when I load the phpinfo()

Comment: Normally internal server error occurs when .htaccess has error or undefined code. Maybe the problem is with your code. You should complete what you needed like requesting a.html and reponding b.html and see if the problem exist. Thanks

Comment: @FedericoCeli: Please post your entire `.htaccess` file so that we can dig into it to see where the problem may be.

Comment: @MikeAnthony well, it's empty. As I write something out of the comment tag it starts giving me the error.

Comment: @silentboy yes, I've already tried it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the error occurs for *every single*  type of instruction you put in the file (that is, caching, `FilesMatch`, `ErrorDocument`, etc), there are two possible options that I can think of right now:

1. The encoding of your `.htaccess` file is not compatible with the server you're running. Try converting it to ANSI, and then try again (Apache does not support [Byte Order Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark), so you'd need to save it to ANSI, or UTF-8, without the BOM). If that does not work:
2. `AllowOverride` is not set correctly, or not at all. If you have access to the Virtual Host/Directory configuration, you'll need to enable it by adding the line `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory>` container.

Comment: 1. Yes, I encode in UTF-8; 

2. I already did this (I'm taliking about the httpd.conf file)

`<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>`

Comment: And have you made sure that there is no BOM? You can check for errors in your Apache error logs.

Comment: And if you leave the file empty, what happens?

Comment: It says `RewriteEngine not allowed here` but in my htppd.conf I both have `<Directory "path_here">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>` and also for the <Directory></Directory>

Comment: Then your hosting service provider does not allow `mod_rewrite` at all - you'll probably need to consult their support desk (or see if they have a knowledge-base or Wiki) for further information. What provider are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see now that you're using localhost...

Comment: What other `.conf` files are there? Check to see if any of them mention `AllowOverride`, and make sure that it is set correctly there.

Comment: Great! I think you did! I changed every single `<Directory>` in the file and now it works, I think! But I have now another problem (due to my ignorance of the topic), here's what i get: `The requested URL /Users/.../Sites/.../index.php was not found on this server.` While well... It does exist.

Comment: Here's what I put in the urlbar `http://127.0.0.1/~.../..../alice.html` Needless to say, `http://127.0.0.1/~.../..../index.php` works fine.

And here is the code `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^alice.html$ index.php`

Comment: Did it! All I did was to set `RewriteBase   /~username/sitefolder/`. Thank you very much to all of you guys. Your help was priceless. Have a great weekend!

Comment: You're very welcome - glad I could help somewhere along the lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to remove the code `RewriteEngine on` and the URL remapping or the URL redirecting is still functioning well, then you do not have to put that code in your `.htaccess` file, for your HTTP server was already configured that the rewrite engine is on. But if you've tried to remove it and the rewriting or the redirecting stop, then you must include all your `.htaccess` codes in your question. Then if it's empty, then why you need to turn the `RewriteEngine on` if you're not going to apply even a single `RewriteRule`?

Have you ever tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^notexist.html$ /index.html
```

And try to visit *yourdomain.com/notexist.html* if it's URL remapping into */index.html*.

Comment: No, it's not working either.

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php

It's all I have, just so I could try and see if it worked.

Comment: Did you try to rewrite somethin'?

Comment: Try my new updates and if did not work then remove `Options +FollowSymlinks` first, and if it's still not workin' then try to remove `RewriteEngine on` and check the result.

Comment: I've tried all possible combinations, unfortunately it's still not working...

Comment: Try to rewrite the page that's not named as `index`. Or there's a problem on the configuration of your HTTP server. What is the name of the folder where your `index` is located?