# htaccess apache 2.2 error

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I've moved my site to enother hosting and got error 500...
Cant understand where error in this htaccess. 
There was everything OK on the old hosting.

when I clear htaccess, I can see my mainpage but cant open enother.

Apache 2.2.27

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^admin /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)?$ /frontend/web/$1
```

I think this is wrong htaccess, cause old hosting was on nginx..

There is nginx config, please help me to translate it to apache:

```
location /backend {
try_files $uri /backend/index.php?$args;
}
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
deny  all;
}
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Look into http servers error log file. There you can _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: It says: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Comment: OK, so obviously you create a redirection loop. I'd say it is the last line. Since it does not carry an `L` flag the rewrite process will be restarted and it looks like that pattern matches _all_ requests...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe new hosting doesn't allow usage of mod_rewrite?

Take a look:

- [Error 500 with .htaccess edits but mod_rewrite is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849296/error-500-with-htaccess-edits-but-mod-rewrite-is-loaded)
- [.htaccess mod_rewrite > 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205456/htaccess-mod-rewrite-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: enother site works good, but it have different structure and htaccess with another RewriteRule